# How to get fedex api key?

Tags: api, drupal-7, fedex

I have registered in [Fedex](https://www.fedex.com/us/). I want to configure fedex for drupal site which has **ubercart**. I have enabled **uc_fedex** module.

I want these values for **FEDEX API** for **Production**:

```
   FedEx Web Services API User Key 

   FedEx Web Services API Password 

   FedEx Account # 

   FedEx Meter #
```

Where can I get those values in the **Fedex Account** ? Can any one guide me with this. ?

Also after putting these values what else should I do in-order to make **Fedex** work for my site??I have enabled **ups** too in my site. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

you must log into the fedex developer center: http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/web-services/index.html

four steps are required-> 1- Download and read docs , 2-Develop and Test, 3-Certification (only for shipping, pickup services). 4- Move to production.

In order to receive an approval for rate services, tracking and fedex locator just go to step 4 Move to production and fill all the information that appears when you press "Get Production Key" Button.

[image]

FedEx will send you an email with your key, meter number and password.

with that information you can put it at your app.
brgds

Comment: Worth noting the site won't work if you have an adblocker enabled, you'll get redirected to the Fedex homepage when you try to click on any of the 'steps'.

Comment: @JarvisJohnson in my experience when you register for first time you need to logout and then login again. otherwise the 4 options will redirect you to homepage. but probably has a relation with adblocker.

Comment: Ah interesting @s_h - that could be it as well.  Frustrating experience either way.

Answer (score 0):

When you contact FedEx for the credentials, they send you two mails. One that contains the account number, meter number and web services key, and the other contains the web services password.

https://www.xadapter.com/can-find-web-services-password/